# Generating multilevel map by bifurcating key

Tags: java

I have a map with keys abc_cd_de, abc_cd_ef, abc_de_fr

Now what I want to have is a 3 level map in this scenario.

And this must be dynamic as per no of _ in key

Comment: @Marco Forberg That's what I am looking for. i.e. If there is any API or else I have to implement my own logic.

Answer (score 1):

> A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K, V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.

You can use Multimap in java to do that

[**SEE HERE**](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: how can it give me multiple level map

Answer (score 0):

I use HashMaps like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>> yourLevelMap= new HashMap<string,HashMap<string, HashMap<String,String>>>();
```

Just define HashMaps as values and thus create another Array level.